# why does qcli generate 600 fail on a qtum node?

Tags: blockchain

I have installed a qtum node using docker - http://book.qtum.site/en/part1/qtum-docker.html#new-blocks-on-demand

I get these results -

```
/dapp # qcli generate 600
error code: -1
error message:
CreateNewBlock: TestBlockValidity failed:  (code 0)
/dapp # qcli getbalance
0.00000000
/dapp # qcli info
error code: -32601
error message:
Method not found
/dapp # qcli getinfo
{
  "deprecation-warning": "WARNING: getinfo is deprecated and will be fully removed in 0.16. Projects should transition to using getblockchaininfo, getnetworkinfo, and getwalletinfo before upgrading to 0.16",
  "version": 150200,
  "protocolversion": 70016,
  "walletversion": 139900,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "stake": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 200183,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "connections": 12,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": {
    "proof-of-work": 1.52587890625e-05,
    "proof-of-stake": 1349986.126276783
  },
  "testnet": true,
  "moneysupply": 100780732,
  "keypoololdest": 1535027613,
  "keypoolsize": 2000,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00400000,
  "errors":
```

Basically the balance is not increasing which is at variance to what the docs say. I cannot find a gitter for qtum. Any ideas for this error?